# C++ local variables and registers

Tags: c++

I often saw that compiler put local function variables in registers. And I have a question regarding this.

If I use some class member variable (integral/pointer, etc...) heavily, does it make sense, to temporary copy it to local variable, work with it, and than copy result to class member?

For example (fill one way ptr list):

```
struct MyClass{

    struct ObjectHolder{
        ObjectHolder* next_free;
    };
    ObjectHolder *next_free = nullptr;

    void fill(){
        ObjectHolder *copy_of_free = next_free ;  // copy to register?

        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
           ObjectHolder &obj = array[i];

           // build chain of pointers
           obj.next_free = copy_of_free;
           copy_of_free  = &obj;
        }

        next_free = copy_of_free;                 // back to memory
    }
}
```

Comment: In general (i.e. non real-time processing): 1. Make it work 2. Make it work *right* 3. benchmark and profile if it is too slow, and then fix the slow bits.

Comment: The compiler may do it by itself anyway.

Comment: @crashmstr I think you are wrong. It is always better to know experience that who already did this, than step on a rake (when you can avoid this).

Comment: @tower120 The problem is that every persons experience will be different.  Different compilers, slightly different code, etc.  Premature optimization is a well established anti-pattern.  Don't do it.

Comment: @Quentin can I read about this somewhere? I read only about recommendations to keep local variables number as small as possible, so compiler can use registers for them.

Comment: @Quentin Trusting the compiler to do that is like trusting that a compiler will make `const` functions and references faster. Technically, its possible. In practice, its probably never done.

Comment: next_free is a global variable and not a local variable.

Comment: @NeilKirk is that better now?

Comment: @tower120 I'm not saying to use Bubble Sort when we know that Mergesort and Quicksort are much faster. I'm saying that things like worrying about registers are not something that many developers need to deal with and are probably not ever the problem point.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams The point is, never try and blindly make micro-optimizations like this one. They may or may not work, or even get in the way of the compiler. If you encounter performance issues, profile, try optimizations where needed, and profile again. One of the strengths of C and C++ is that the compiler is free to stretch your code inside out if that leads to unchanged behaviour and better performance, make use of it.

Comment: (I'm confused...this example just sets all obj.next_free to this.next_free. Is no one worried about that?)

Comment: I heartily agree with @Quentin. Make sure you know what prevents a compiler from optimizing and avoid that, but leave the work to the experts (the compiler). They know how many registers your CPU has etc.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams hey, if it's gonna crash, at least it's gonna crash efficiently ;)

Comment: @crashmstr Well, you should listen what Scott Meyers says about cache optimizations here http://vimeo.com/97337258. That's, of course, about treading, but nevertheless.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams - You're right. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What you described in your code goes beyond copying of member variables into local variables to enable register placement. In essence, your question illustrates the difference between two approaches:

1. Fully computing a result locally before writing it to member variables, vs.
2. Writing intermediate results to member variables as you go through computations.

Your program follows approach #1. It is more robust than #2, because the object remains in a consistent state while the computation is performed.

Approach #1 may give the compiler more opportunities to optimize your code, too. However, this is a secondary effect; your object staying consistent during the computation is more important.

Comment: You see, there is no heavy computations. It just fill linked list, so I can iterate it then. But the list can be really long (a few thousands objects). So I worry, that each 3 ops I will pull/push to memory.

Comment: @tower120 It does not matter if the computation is complex or not: the difference is between storing intermediate results in member variables vs. keeping intermediate results local. Keeping even simple computations local offers the compiler more venues for optimizing the code that it generates for you.

Comment: You know, I am a little bit shocked, but gcc generated completely identical asm code - http://goo.gl/BFrlpz

Comment: @tower120 I think the point is that the optimizations are kindof an after thought for this. The number one reason however is the more things are local, the less weird side effects you get from calling your code. This is more maintainable in the long run, and makes it much easier to do things like split up functions, add multithreaded stuff, ect.

Answer (score -1):

There is no any sense in these manipulations because the compiler itself can place the value of the data member in the register optimising the code. Moreover if you will place the data member in the local variable it can occur such a way that this only makes the code more compound.

Comment: And how it "MAY" do this? There is no guarantee for compiler that I will not touch that variable from another thread.

Comment: @tower120 Of course you can declare even 10 local variables but this will not make your code more optimized. I do not see any sense in your reference to threads.

Comment: @tower120 To be pedantic: in pre-C++11 there is no concept of threads, so that's up to your compiler/platform as to what guarantees/assumptions hold.  In C++11 the compiler can guarantee that the variable isn't touched in another thread.  More accurately, it gets to assume that it is not touched in another thread.  If it is, it's up you to put in the appropriate sequencing operations to ensure that you have not created a race condition (AKA: Undefined Behaviour).

Answer (score -2):

This is supposed to be an optimisation which makes your code run faster, at the price of code that is less readable and therefore more likely to contain bugs. In your case, I don't quite understand what the code does, but it's obvious that there is a bug. And there is a good chance that the compiler is clever enough to do by itself what you are trying to do.

In general, the rule is: Only do speed optimisations after you have measured the speed of the code, and found that it is too slow. If it's fast enough that you didn't bother measuring the speed, then it is fast enough. Then measure *before* and *after* you made changes, and only use your changes if the speed goes up *and the code still works correctly*.

Instead of using optimisations that reduce your code quality, you should find the places in your code where you do things in an unnecessarily complicated way, and make things simpler and more efficient that way. Removing unneeded complications tends to make your code more correct, more maintainable, and faster.

Comment: It fill one way linked list.

Answer (score -2):

Let the micro optimizations to the compiler, using `register` might make your code slower as you prevent the compiler from optimizing the way it want.
On performance issues, try to avoid big waste of time (such as copying large objects when you can pass them by reference) and optimize only when it is proven (by a benchmark) that you need to. by the way the benchmark will tell you what to optimize.

Comment: How, for the name of God, I prevent optimization here? How using registers can slow down this? Maybe you thought that I suggest to use `register` keyword (hint for compiler)?

Comment: Nicolas thinks that the user uses up precious registers with badly chosen (by the user) register variables. But since the register keyword is non-binding and has been out of fashion since the late 80s I assume you can sprinkle them liberally over your code if that makes you feel good. But don't expect different code being generated.

Comment: @tower120 Simply, by confusing the optimiser which is primed to recognise some common usage patterns and to optimise those. When you try to outsmart the compiler, you break its expectations.